# Do I have to redo the prayers I missed?

Tags: salat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does a Muslim have to pray all the prayers that he left out?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33/does-a-muslim-have-to-pray-all-the-prayers-that-he-left-out)

If I think about all of the days I missed salat it could count up to months of missed prayer days. I need to make all those day up but I don't know how.

Is asking for forgiveness for the prayers I missed enough or should I make them all up and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask forgiveness, dropping prayers is dropping Islam! Welcome back to Islam!
Please read this [fatwa](http://islamqa.com/en/ref/2199).
I quote the following from it:

> If he repents and starts to pray the obligatory prayers and to fast in Ramadaan, and he continues to do so, then he is considered to be a Muslim, and the prayers and fasts that he deliberately failed to do in the past do not have to be made up, because the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Islam wipes out what came before and repentance wipes out what came before”, and because the Sahaabah (may Allaah be pleased with them), when they fought the apostates at the time of [Abu Bakr] al-Siddeeq (may Allaah be pleased with him), they did not tell those who came back to Islam to make up the fasts or prayers, and they [the Sahaabah] are the most knowledgeable of the sharee’ah of Allaah after the Messengers, peace and blessings of Allaah be upon them.