# Missing Salah because I lost track of time - How do I make up for this?

Tags: salat, forgiveness

I had to pray my isha but I got caught up doing something else and didn’t notice how much time had passed. When I was done I checked the time and realised I missed Isha by 3 minutes. I quickly prayed the 4 fardh. Did I get ghunna (sin) for this?

If I do get ghunna for this how can I make it up and how do I know if I am forgiven?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does a Muslim have to make up for all the prayers that he left without any excuse?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33/does-a-muslim-have-to-make-up-for-all-the-prayers-that-he-left-without-any-excus)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are sinful for missing prayer.
You should always put prayer first above your other priorities.
You should pray Kazah and repent sincerely for neglecting the prayer.

You can make it up by repenting and trying your best not to make a repeat of this incident again. Perhaps change your schedule so that way you put prayer first above anything else just so you can get it out of your way and bless your work.

You will know you’re forgiven by the following:

- You don’t miss prayer as often (if Allah is mad at you, he takes the privilege of prayer away from you which is why some stop praying altogether)
- You sin less
- You feel a boost in your mood, positivity in general
- You will Feel Calm And Relaxed

Answer (score 0):

### You won't know you're forgiven, so continuously seek forgiveness

According to this [IslamQA article](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/111783/how-can-he-make-up-for-missed-prayers):

You either perform the prayer as soon as you remember, such as you did, or if you deliberately decided not to pray then you must repent and seek forgiveness:

> [If] He missed it for a reason, such as falling asleep or forgetting it. There is no sin on him in this case, but he has to make it up when he wakes up or remembers it.
>
> It was narrated from Anas ibn Maalik (may Allaah be pleased with him) that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: "Whoever forgets a prayer, let him offer it as soon as he remembers, for there is no expiation for it other than that."
> — Narrated by al-Bukhaari (572) and Muslim (684); Muslim narrated an additional phrase: "or sleeps and misses it".

---

n.b. from my own studies with alkauthar, I was taught "there is no such thing as qaza (kazah) prayer". Do not fall into the trap of thinking you can  (casually) make up prayers after their fixed time.